# Refactor jQuery's .on Function

Tags: jquery

```
//MAIN HEADER - When looking Away From Field, "Disables" The Field
$("#main_form").on("focusout", "#main_header", disableField);
//MAIN HEADER - When Clicking On The Field, Returns It To Editing Mode
$("#main_form").on("click", "#main_header", enableField);
```

Is there a way to refactor this so I use a single function, and just add the variables as I go along the page? This goes on for about 15 more elements

Comment: You are setting the same `focusout` and `click` for each of these 15 elements?

Comment: Indeed. It's an editor of some sorts. I'm kind of figuring out what it is as I go along.

Comment: What sort of elements are you dealing with? Can you show your relevant HTML (or at least a subset of it to reproduce your problem)?

Comment: I actually Got the answer a couple lines below. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this maybe? If I understand correctly

```
$("#main_form").on("click","input",function(){
    $(this).enable() //or something?
})

$("#main_form").on("focusout","input",function(){
    $(this).disable() //or something?
})
```

Comment: Well, I want to eliminate the entire .on(------) part.....Is there some way to store this in a function or something?

Comment: These two lines should cover the whole `#main_form`. You could use a case switch also if you want it to only be in one function

Comment: Well, I've got textareas as well. Can I just add textarea after the input pseudo-selector?

Comment: you can give all your stuff the same class, and then use: `$("#main_form").on("click",".class",function(){
    $(this).enable() //or something?
})`

Comment: It Does Indeed. Thanks @Sam Creamer!

Answer (score 2):

You can pass an object to `.on` like `event : function`:

```
$("#main_form").on({
    focusout : disableField,
    click : enableField
}, "#main_header");
```

Comment: OK - this looks like a great way, except it doesn't treat any handler I'd give it - it only uses the static `#main_header`...

Comment: I mean that I have more than 1 element, I've got 15 other ones besides `#main_header`.

Comment: @TomGranot-Scalosub You can change `#main_header` to whatever selector. If you want all input and text area for example : `$("#main_form").on({}, "input, textarea");`

Answer (score 1):

Sure, I'd suggest:

```
$("#main_form").on("focusout click", "#main_header", function(e){
    switch (e.type) {
        case 'focusout':
            disableField();
            break;
        case 'click':
            enableField();
            break;
    }
});
```

To reduce your code slightly:

```
var eventHandlingMap = {
    'focusout' : disableField,
    'click' : enableField
}

$('#main_form').on('focusout click', '.classOfElementsToActUpon', function(e){
    // will call the appropriate function:
    eventHandlingMap[e.type]();
    // 'this' will be the element acted upon:
    $(this).css('color', 'green'); /* or whatever... */
});
```

Comment: OK - this is more like it. However - the #main_header ID will need to change. Is there some way to pass the acted-upon element into this function, and not get stuck with a static one?

Comment: Should `function()` be `function(e)`?

Comment: @j08691, it shoulld. Sorry, answering via iPad...it's more awkward than I'd like and I tend to miss things.

Comment: @DavidThomas - No problem, understood. I tried answering from my tablet once and gave up. For some things I just need a real keyboard.

Comment: Tablets are great for Game Of Thrones. Coding? eh. Not So Much:)

Answer (score 1):

```
function setFocusAndClick(arrayOfIds) {
    $.each(arrayOfIds, function(i,v) {
        $('#' + v).on('focusout', $('#' + v), disableField);
        $('#' + v).on('click', $('#' + v), enableField);

    });
}

setFocusAndClick({'main_form', 'second_form'});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to refactor existing method to reduce code duplication. Refactoring is not about it at all.

You can wrap, your logic just into a function, like this:

```
function handleEvent(callbacks, selector) {
 $("#main_form").on(callbacks, selector); 
}

// And then
handleEvent({

    focusout : disableField,
    click : enableField

}, "#main_header")
```